# Normalizing the MFCC

Tags: audio, conv-neural-network, mfcc

do i need to get the normalized mel spectogram from librosa library or I dont need it to be normalized and should be ready for the CNN model ?

I tried it without normalizin the values of mel spectogram and it works just fine. However, the training time is slow. I am wondering if i should normalize it first before proceeding with the modelling.

This is my function for getting the spectogram and inputting it into the CNN model:

```
def get_spectogram(path, mfcc):
x, sr = librosa.load(path, res_type='kaiser_fast')
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=aug, sr=sr, n_mels=mfcc)
spec = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
return spec
```

Comment: Do you use batch normalisation in the CNN?

Comment: yes sir i use batch normalisation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in majority of cases you should normalise MFCC, and the most popular procedure is [Cepstral mean and variance normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstral_mean_and_variance_normalization) (CMVN). You will find it implemented in Python in e.g. [SpeechPy](https://github.com/astorfi/speechpy/blob/master/README.rst#global-cepstral-mean-and-variance-normalization-cmvn).

Why your code "works just fine" despite seemingly lack of normalization? As you explained in the comments, you are actually doing normalization - the "batch normalization" step. It will do, but you might squeeze some extra points by doing the normalization yourself.

Comment: Does doing CMVN in the mel spectogram output do ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The normalization would be of the coefficients themselves. Still, batch normalization will work just fine.